# How to create a heatmap with dark purple

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I am wanting to create a heatmap with dark purple as shown below:

[image: darkpurple]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(0)

uniform_data1 = np.random.rand(10, 12)

ax1 = sns.heatmap(uniform_data1, cbar_kws={'label': 'score1'}, cmap="BuPu")
```

I have tried `cmap` equal to `"BuPu"`, `"PuBu"` or `"Purples"` but all didn't quite give me the right colour. Would really be nice if I could have the same purple colours as shown in the picture above.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: "but all didn't quite give me the right colour." What exactly was wrong about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

uniform_data1 = np.random.rand(10, 12)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1 = sns.heatmap(uniform_data1, cbar_kws={'label': 'score1'}, cmap=sns.cubehelix_palette(8))
plt.show()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be4uV.jpg)

I am not sure if `sns.cubehelix_palette(8)` is exact what you desire. You could look at seaborn's [choosing color palettes](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html) page to find more options.

Comment: Glad to hear that it works, it was my first answer on stack overflow. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
cmap=sns.cubehelix_palette()
```

[image: heatmap]